# How to display only companies which belongs to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to access show page based on the current user.id == company.user_id, i want show particular user added company details only, when the company_path link click.

companies_controller.rb file is

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @companies = Company.all            
  end

  def show
    @company = Company.where(user_id:company.user_id)
    @company_user_id = current_user.id               
  end

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:c_name, :c_description)
  end

  def find_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:id]) 
  end

end
```

routes.rb file is as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :jobs
  resources :companies
  root 'jobs#index'
end
```

rake routes information is as,

```
          DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)                          jobs#destroy
  user_companies GET    /users/:user_id/companies(.:format)          companies#index
                 POST   /users/:user_id/companies(.:format)          companies#create
new_user_company GET    /users/:user_id/companies/new(.:format)      companies#new
edit_user_company GET    /users/:user_id/companies/:id/edit(.:format) companies#edit
    user_company GET    /users/:user_id/companies/:id(.:format)      companies#show
                 PATCH  /users/:user_id/companies/:id(.:format)      companies#update
                 PUT    /users/:user_id/companies/:id(.:format)      companies#update
                 DELETE /users/:user_id/companies/:id(.:format)      companies#destroy
           users GET    /users(.:format)                             users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                             users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                         users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                 PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                         users#destroy
            root GET    /                                            jobs#index
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap company resource inside user resources:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :companies
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you very much, but in the CompaniesController,   def show is not handling the content correctly

Comment: thank s a lot, this is the error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies", :user_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id], possible unmatched constraints: [:user_id]
Extracted source (around line #55):
53
54
55
56
57
58
              

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link_to "Companies", user_company_path(@company) %></a>
              
            </li>

Comment: When you use `user_company_path(@company)`, your path need a `@user` and a `@company`. I saw that you just pass @company param in the path. It should be `user_company_path(current_user,  @company) `

Comment: thank you very much supporting for me, but still has  a issue,    No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #55):
53
54
55
56
57
58
              

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link_to "Companies", user_company_path(current_user, @company) %></a>
              
            </li>

Comment: its due to value of `@company` variable is nil

Comment: but company has value, @company=Company.last
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY "companies"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Company id: 4, c_name: "VIrtusa Corperation", c_description: "In 2009, Virtusa acquired InSource,[4] a technolog...", created_at: "2018-02-03 03:38:23", updated_at: "2018-02-03 03:38:23", user_id: 1>
irb(main):003:0>

Answer (score 0):

Modify show action as

```
def show
  @company = Company.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  @company_user_id = current_user.id
end
```

and modify your routes as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :jobs
  resources :companies, except: :show do
    get :show, on: :collection, as: :show
  end
  root 'jobs#index'
end
```

and instead of following

```
<%= link_to "Companies", company_path(@company) %>
```

use path as

```
<%= link_to "Companies", show_companies_path %>
```

I hope this will help you !!!

Comment: thanks, but it will show error , No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #55):
53
54
55
56
57
58
              

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link_to "Companies", company_path(@company) %></a>
              
            </li>

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but still having issue, Couldn't find Company with 'id'=
Extracted source (around line #71):
69
70
71
72
73
74
              

  def find_company
   @company = Company.find(params[:id]) 
  end

Comment: why are you trying to find company as you want to display companies which belongs to current user. Method `find_company` not should be avoided for show action

Comment: i'm new to ruby on rails, can you give me to solution

Comment: From where `find_company` method is get called, just remove that part so method will not get invoke, you can remove method too if not required.

Comment: now i have another issue ,  Showing C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2/app/views/companies/show.html.haml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `c_name' for #<Company::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000e640560>
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
2
3
4
5
              
%h2{:class => "show_job", :id => "message"}= @company.c_name
%h4{:class => "show_job_descr"}= simple_format @company.c_description
%br/
%br/
= link_to "Delete", company_path(@company), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }

Comment: This is not a good option. You are using the show method to display many companies. The index method is the right one. As companies is a nested resource for user, it is enough to call the index method with a user_id. The path is user_companies_path(user_id).

Answer (score 0):

The show method is not supposed to show many companies. You should use the index method.

The best option is to define companies as nested resource in users (as eugene suggested).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :companies
  end
end
```

Then, in the controller:

```
def index
  if params[:user_id] && @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    @companies = @user.companies
  else
    @companies = Company.all
  end
end
```

In the view, to call the index you should

```
<%= link_to "View companies", user_companies_path(@user.id) %>
```

This would display companies for a user in @user. If you want to display current_user companies, just replace @user by current_user

Comment: it shows error, ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Companies#index
Showing C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #55 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"companies", :user_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:user_id]
Extracted source (around line #55):
53
54
55
56
57
58
              

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link_to "My Profile", user_companies_path(@user_id) %></a>
              
            </li>

Comment: This is because you are passing an empty user_id. Where are you writing the link_to? (`<%= link to "View companies", user_companies_path(@user.id) %>`). Does the user exist and is persisted?. Well. I see you wrote **@user_id**, and I wrote **@user.id**

Comment: thanks for your help, but stil have a issue, Showing C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #55 raised:

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #55):
53
54
55
56
57
58
              

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link to "View companies", user_companies_path(@user.id) %> </a>

Comment: Then `@user` is nil. Did you set `@user` in the controller? If not, you can use current_user (**current_user.id**)

Comment: still have a issue, undefined method `to' for #<#      

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link to "View companies", user_companies_path(current_user.id) %> </a>
              
            </li>                                                                                                     in the controller (index) : if params[:user_id] && @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
               @companies = @user.companies
            else
              @companies = Company.all
            end

Comment: **link_to** is missing the underscore.

Comment: Great. Please accept this answer with the green tick, so that people know this is a good way to go. If not, other users need to read all comments to find out an answer worked for you. Regards.

Comment: but still have a another issue, if user is not log in system andalso  when the  user log out system it will show error, ndefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" <%= link_to "Your Profile", user_companies_path(current_user.id) %> </a>

Comment: But this is right!. If the user is not logged, there is no current_user (current_user is nil). It makes no sense to view his companies. You must only show the link if the user is logged.